# How do I include library from github in python project without pip?

Tags: python, git, python-2.7, heroku, pip

I'm not sure what's the python way to include another library getting from github.

I'm planning to use this library https://github.com/nim901/gfycat which right now I just downloaded the `zip` and extract it and put that in `lib` folder. I have to checkin this library into the repo to work in Heroku. Is there a way to install the lib automatically from github?

Comment: If you're using Heroku...why can't you just define a git-backed pip requirement? https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#git-backed-distributions

Comment: @rnevius heh, this looks like a much easier solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku has support for git-backed python dependencies via pip: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-pip#git-backed-distributions

I believe this fits your requirements better than checking the actual libraries into git. From the link above:

> Anything that works with a standard pip requirements file will work as expected on Heroku.
>
> Thanks to pip’s Git support, you can install a Python package that is hosted on a remote Git repository.
>
> For example:
>
> `git+git://github.com/kennethreitz/requests.git`

Answer (score 1):

You can add the library as a [submodule](http://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) of your project. This will allow you to update it like any other git repository.

Is `git clone https://github.com/nim901/gfycat.git` and then `git pull` automatic enough? If this solution fits you and you need additional instructions, I will add them.

Answer (score 0):

From how I'm reading your question, it sounds like you're trying to install the module to your system in order to be able to import it into projects and such.

Download the zip, extract it to wherever, and open up a terminal window to the same directory. Then just run `python setup.py install` from within the directory, and it should install into your system-wide `site-packages` directory for python.

I would have to recommend that you install it into it's own environment managed by `virtualenv` (https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), but it's not necessary.